# Can I use a JSF 2.0 compatible component library in JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, tomahawk

When I go to http://myfaces.apache.org/core22, I see MyFaces JSF 2.2 implementation.

But I'm not seeing Tomahawk for JSF 2.2 in http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk. Can I use Tomahawk for JSF 2.0 in JSF 2.2?

Comment: _"Does anyone know if I can use tomahawk for jsf2.0 in myfaces jsf 2.2 environment?"_   try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no API/spec-related (and therefore per definition also no technical) limitations for using a JSF 2.0 compatible component library in JSF 2.2.

Those limitations only exist(ed) when you want to use a JSF 1.x compatible component library in JSF 2.x, primarily because of the replacement of JSP by Facelets as default view technology (JSP tags doesn't work in Facelets).

So, you should be able to just use "Tomahawk for JSF 2.0" or any other JSF 2.0 compatible component library in JSF 2.2 (and 2.1 and 2.3).